# How to delete a character off a string with variables and functions in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my bit of troublesome code:

```
for x in range (50, 150):

    print(x, ';', end='  ', sep=' ')
```

I'm trying to print the numbers 50 through 150 separated with semicolons and spaces so it looks something like this: '50; 51; 52; 53;' and etcetera. I don't want to have the last semicolon at the end, but I can't figure out how to delete it.

I've already tried the [:-1] and .rstrip methods, none of which I can think of a solution to, beacause they both delete all of the semicolons when applied like so:

```
(x, ';'.rstrip(';'), end='  ', sep=' ') 

(x, ';'[:-1], end='  ', sep=' ').
```

I'm not sure if I'm coding this incorrectly or if there's just some algorithm of functions I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the whole range to `print()` in one go:

```
print(*range(50, 150), sep='; ')
```

Note the `*`; it expands the values produced by the `range()` into separate arguments to `print()`, which then uses the `sep` argument between those arguments.

The alternative would be to use the [`str.join()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to join the integers into a long string and *then* print those values, but you'd have to convert them all to strings first:

```
print('; '.join(map(str, range(50, 150))))
```

Here the [`map()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) converts each integer yielded by `range()` into a `str` object.

If you *must* use a loop, then you should loop to 148 and use an extra, *separate* `print()` call to print the last value, and use the `end` argument to produce your separator:

```
for x in range(50, 149):
    print(x, end='; ')
print(149)
```

Using `str.rstrip()` would only work if you had already built the whole string and needed to remove the trailing `'; '` from that string. It won't work when using `print()`, as you don't have the whole string to operate on at that time.

Answer (score 0):

How about `print('; '.join(map(str, range(50, 150))))`